# Removing permutations from a list of tuples

Tags: python, python-2.7

Any help with this question is appreciated.

I have a list of tuples

```
a = [(1,2), (2,1), (1,3), (1,4), (4,1)]
```

and I need to remove duplicates of a certain type: (1,2) and (2,1) are considered duplicates according to my definition. Required output

```
a = [(1,2), (1,3), (1,4)]
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could sort them and then remove duplicates with `set()`:

```
>>> set(tuple(sorted(l)) for l in a)
    set([(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4)])
```

Comment: The first approach won't work.  (1,1) is a tuple, but it will become frozenset([1]).  The 2nd approach works though.

Comment: @DmitryRubanovich: `(1, 1)` is the identity permutation, so `(1, 1)` and `(1,)` or `frozenset([1])` are equivalent.

Comment: he didn't say that the tuples were themselves permutations.  He   only said that he wanted to remove tuples which were permutations of other tuples present in the list.  Removing (1,1) and substituting it with (1,) would not do that.

Comment: @DmitryRubanovich: Ah, you're right. I'll remove the potentially buggy code.

Comment: @Blender, if object type needed to be maintained, could `list(set(tuple(sorted(l)) for l in a))` be used?