# remove duplicates from 2d lists regardless of order

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, duplicates

I have a 2d list

```
a = [[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 1], [2, 3], [3, 1], [3, 2]]
```

How can I get the result:

```
result = [[1,2],[1,3],[2,3]]
```

Where duplicates are removed regardless of their order of the inner lists.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing permutations from a list of tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15352995/removing-permutations-from-a-list-of-tuples)  -- which by the way is a better solution than the answers posted so far.

Comment: `list(map(list, (set(tuple(sorted(l)) for l in a))))`, borrowing the logic from the duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [3]: b = []
In [4]: for aa in a:
...:     if not any([set(aa) == set(bb) for bb in b if len(aa) == len(bb)]):
...:         b.append(aa)
In [5]: b
Out[5]: [[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3]]
```

Comment: how does this handle `[[1,2,1], [1,2]]`?

Comment: good catch, I have not considered that. Need to add another filter for that.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a set to keep track of what lists you have seen:

```
from collections import Counter

a = [[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 1], [2, 3], [3, 1], [3, 2], [1, 2, 1]]

seen = set()
result = []
for lst in a:
    current = frozenset(Counter(lst).items())
    if current not in seen:
        result.append(lst)
        seen.add(current)

print(result)
```

Which outputs:

```
[[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 1]]
```

**Note:** Since lists are not hash able, you can store frozensets of `Counter` objects to detect order less duplicates. This removes the need to sort at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
a = [[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 1], [2, 3], [3, 1], [3, 2]]
aa = [tuple(sorted(elem)) for elem in a]
set(aa)
```

output

```
{(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)}
```

Answer (score -2):

The 'Set' concept would come in handy here. The list you have (which contains duplicates) can be converted to a Set (which will never contain a duplicate).
Find more about Sets here : [Set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set)

Example :

```
l = ['foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'hello']
```

A set can be created directly:

```
s = set(l)
```

now if you check the contents of the list

```
print(s)
>>> {'foo', 'bar', 'hello'}
```

Set will work this way with any iterable object! 
Hope it helps!