# What is the most time efficient way to remove unordered duplicates in a 2D array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, set, python-itertools

I've generated a list of combinations, using `itertools` and I'm getting a result that looks like this:

```
nums = [-5,5,4,-3,0,0,4,-2]
x = [x for x in set(itertools.combinations(nums, 4)) if sum(x)==target]
>>> x = [(-5, 5, 0, 4), (-5, 5, 4, 0), (5, 4, -3, -2), (5, -3, 4, -2)]
```

What is the most time-complexity wise efficient way of removing unordered duplicates, such as `x[0]` and `x[1]` are the duplicates. Is there anything built in to handle this?

My general approach would be to create a counter of all elements in one and compare to the next. Would this be the best approach?

Thank you for any guidance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing permutations from a list of tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15352995/removing-permutations-from-a-list-of-tuples)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you want to find unordered duplicates the best way to go is by typecasting. *Typecast* them as *`set`*. Since set only contains ***immutable*** elements. So, I made a set of *`tuples`*.

> Note:
>   The best way to eliminate ***duplicates*** is by making a *`set`* of the given elements.

```
>>> set(map(tuple,map(sorted,x)))
{(-3, -2, 4, 5), (-5, 0, 4, 5)}
```

Answer (score 4):

The best way is to not generate the duplicates in the first place.

The idea is to first create all possible combinations of values that appear multiple times, where each appears 0, 1, ... times. Then, we complete them with all possible combinations of the unique elements.

```
from itertools import combinations, product, chain
from collections import Counter

nums = [-5,5,4,-3,0,0,4,-2]

def combinations_without_duplicates(nums, k):
    counts = Counter(nums)
    multiples = {val: count for val, count in counts.items() if count >= 2 }
    uniques = set(counts) - set(multiples)              
    possible_multiples = [[[val]*i for i in range(count+1)] for val, count in multiples.items()]
    multiples_part = (list(chain(*x)) for x in product(*possible_multiples))
    # omit the ones that are too long
    multiples_part = (lst for lst in multiples_part if len(lst) <= k)
    # Would be at this point:
    # [[], [0], [0, 0], [4], [4, 0], [4, 0, 0], [4, 4], [4, 4, 0], [4, 4, 0, 0]]
    for m_part in multiples_part:
        missing = k - len(m_part)
        for c in combinations(uniques, missing):
            yield m_part + list(c)


list(combinations_without_duplicates(nums, 4))
```

Output:

```
[[-3, -5, 5, -2],
 [0, -3, -5, 5],
 [0, -3, -5, -2],
 [0, -3, 5, -2],
 [0, -5, 5, -2],
 [0, 0, -3, -5],
 [0, 0, -3, 5],
 [0, 0, -3, -2],
 [0, 0, -5, 5],
 [0, 0, -5, -2],
 [0, 0, 5, -2],
 [4, -3, -5, 5],
 [4, -3, -5, -2],
 [4, -3, 5, -2],
 [4, -5, 5, -2],
 [4, 0, -3, -5],
 [4, 0, -3, 5],
 [4, 0, -3, -2],
 [4, 0, -5, 5],
 [4, 0, -5, -2],
 [4, 0, 5, -2],
 [4, 0, 0, -3],
 [4, 0, 0, -5],
 [4, 0, 0, 5],
 [4, 0, 0, -2],
 [4, 4, -3, -5],
 [4, 4, -3, 5],
 [4, 4, -3, -2],
 [4, 4, -5, 5],
 [4, 4, -5, -2],
 [4, 4, 5, -2],
 [4, 4, 0, -3],
 [4, 4, 0, -5],
 [4, 4, 0, 5],
 [4, 4, 0, -2],
 [4, 4, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`itertools.combinations_with_replacement()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html?highlight=combinations#itertools.combinations_with_replacement).

> Return *r* length subsequences of elements from the input *iterable* allowing individual elements to be repeated more than once.
>
> Combinations are emitted in lexicographic sort order. So, if the input *iterable* is sorted, the combination tuples will be produced in sorted order.
>
> Elements are treated as unique based on their position, not on their value. So if the input elements are unique, the generated combinations will also be unique.

Source: [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html?highlight=combinations#itertools.combinations_with_replacement)