# How to remove duplicate interchanged tuples in the list of tuples?

Tags: python

So basically I have a list of tuples

```
list = [('OPERATIONS SALES', 'ACCOUNT MANAGER'),('ACCOUNT MANAGER', 'OPERATIONS SALES'),('SALESREP REL QUOTE', 'SMART PRICES'), ('SALESREP REL ORDER', 'SMART PRICES'),('SMART PRICES', 'SALESREP REL ORDER')]
```

From which i have to remove inverted duplicates such that 
if ('OPERATIONS SALES', 'ACCOUNT MANAGER') and ('ACCOUNT MANAGER', 'OPERATIONS SALES') exist in the list, I only take one instance of them. I'm new to python.

final output should be like:

```
unique_list = [('OPERATIONS SALES', 'ACCOUNT MANAGER'),('SALESREP REL QUOTE', 'SMART PRICES'), ('SALESREP REL ORDER', 'SMART PRICES')]
```

Comment: Duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59589647/what-is-the-most-time-efficient-way-to-remove-duplicates-in-a-2d-array/59589765#59589765 check this link.

Comment: Thank you, but how to convert them into list

Comment: Use the `list(...)` function on the result.

Comment: cast the result into a list using `list()`.

Comment: s = list(unique_list)

Comment: `list(set([tuple(sorted(x)) for x in lst])) `